# How to display the left side of the value that comes before the last second dot in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a value like "NetWorker 8.2.3.1.Build."

And I have to get only the value "NetWorker 8.2.3.1" in Excel.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: remove from all items a word 'builder'?

Answer (score 4):

A1 = NetWorker 8.2.3.1.Build

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".Build",)
```

or

```
=LEFT(A1,COUNT(FIND(".",A1,ROW($1:$36)))-1)
```

or

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99),4),99))
```

Comment: another alternative  =MID(A1;1;LEN(A1)-LEN(".Build."))

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (if .Build. is not anywhere else in your excel):

1. CTRL + A
2. CTRL + F
3. search for .Build.
4. Replace by ''
   (nothing within the replace field)